# Mono issue with https webservice (only on raspberry, not on Mint x86 or win x86!)

Tags: c#, web-services, mono

I hope anyone has the knowledge to tell me something about the error I run into.

I connect to a webservice generated from WSDL. I run into the same issue, either generated from wsdl.ese or svcutil.exe.

The service connects and works on a mint installation and a win7 installation.
on MS.Net there are no issues, on mono.net I needed the certificate chain handler as written below.

I tried so far:

- changing the app.config so that everything works on said platforms
- adding fault handler for the certificate chain as proposed on this forum (fixed functionality on windows mono.net)

The error message is:
The error message with action '' cannot be ...

leading me to believe that either an empty message is recieved or sent.

unfortunately this whole c# xml serialization blows my mind, and I do not know where to find the sent message te decompose by hand.

wireshark is useless because of the encryption..

Is this a Bug in Mono for ARM or am I missing some certificate on my pi?
I can reach the site in a browser on all platforms.

Rgds

EDIT:

- mono version: 4.6.2 (latest on all platforms) but same effect on 4.4.x
- as taken from chrome:
- Protocol TLS - 1.2
- Key Exchange - ECDHE_RSA
- Key Exchange Group - P-256
- Cipher - AES_128_GCM

Comment: Does it work for `http://` connections? Is the server running TLS 1.2 only?Which version of Mono?

Comment: I can not try http, as the server does not give this option

Comment: PS. trying with curl the site connects etc. showing sslv3 and TLS 1.2 connection. All seems to work well, as I get within the security on all platforms. However there is still one thing I am missing on the raspberry.

Comment: Is the server running TLS 1.2 **only**? If so, update your Mono version to 4.8+ and set the `MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls` to use BoringSSL

Comment: with Curl I can force TLS1.0 and TLS1.1. This works for both. How do I force a lower version in Mono?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the MONO installation in the regular raspbian repository is old.
The bug was indeed in MONO.

follow this thread to install latest:
http://blog.bennymichielsen.be/2016/03/14/getting-up-and-running-with-mono-and-raspberry-pi-3/
or:
https://gist.github.com/tonemackay/21139ff56c1e124659fa

I only tried the first one, worked straight away.

Thanks SushiHangover for your interest.